# extract multiple values from duplicated ID

Tags: r, string

I have a problem with a string variable.
if fact I have a list of patients (with their ID's as string) and the surgical procedures they received (as string as well)

the data presents like that

```
a=c("A","A","A","B","B","B","C","C","C")  #a is patient id
b=c(1:9)
c=c("asfdf","Sdfdsf","sdf","DF","Sdf","sdfds","sdff","cxv","vbnvb") # c is surgical procedure name
df=cbind(a,b,c)
df
     a   b   c       
 [1,] "A" "1" "asfdf" 
 [2,] "A" "2" "Sdfdsf"
 [3,] "A" "3" "sdf"   
 [4,] "B" "4" "DF"    
 [5,] "B" "5" "Sdf"   
 [6,] "B" "6" "sdfds" 
 [7,] "C" "7" "sdff"  
 [8,] "C" "8" "cxv"   
 [9,] "C" "9" "vbnvb"
```

what I want is to produce a dataframe that contains the patient ID and all of the procedure this person received as shown below

I want something like that

"A"    "asfdf|Sdfdsf|sdf"
"B"    "DF|Sdf|sdfds"
"C"    "sdff|cxv|vbnvb"

or separated in 3 columns ( I will collapse them using paste)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `aggregate` with `paste`

```
aggregate(c ~ a, df, FUN = paste, collapse="|")
#  a                c
#1 A asfdf|Sdfdsf|sdf
#2 B     DF|Sdf|sdfds
#3 C   sdff|cxv|vbnvb
```

---

We can also use `data.table` methods to make this faster

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(c = paste(c, collapse="|")), .(a)]
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(a, b, c)
```

Comment: is there a hyperthreaded approach? . I have 6 million entries. the aggregate function seems to be stuck.

Comment: the one using setDT function was much faster (gave the good object is 15mn) Aggregate took more than an hour (no result was delivered). Thanks a lot @akrun